# Azure AD B2C : How to add user created by self service flow to a group

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I wanted to restrict my application to be accessed by a subset of my users present in the azure b2c tenant. How would I do this ?

If my users are being signed up using the self service flow is there any way we can programmatic add a group to the user.?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Custom B2C Policies you can do one of the following;

1) Use a REST Provider Technical profile to call out to a custom API to add the user to a group. (Currently B2C does not support group membership nativly), you would then need to do that again on each signin to retrieve the mebership.

2) If its just to identify groups of users just use an attribute. ie `Application1=True/False`, `Application2=True/False`

If the value is set on an attribute rather than a group you are then able to use it for signin decisions within the user journey as part of a pre-condition. Or you can pass the Claim to the app and let it decide what to do with the user.

If you are not using custom policies, unfortunately this is not yet possible.